# No feature of AttributedString is working other than strikethrough

Tags: java, text, awt, bufferedimage, java-2d

I have to write a string to `BufferedImage`. I am using `AtrributedString`. `TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH` is working. Superscript, Subscript and others are not working.

```
public class TextAttributesSuperscript  {

    static String Background = "input.png";
    static int curX = 10;
    static int curY = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AttributedString attributedString= new AttributedString("this is data. this data should be super script");

        attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLACK);


        attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 18), 30,33);
        attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLUE, 29,33);
    attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT,TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER,30,33);

        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(Background));
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.drawString(attributedString.getIterator(), curX, curY);
        g.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("output.png"));
    }
}
```

While executing above code. The superscript part was not working(the text was not getting printed like superscript)

Comment: @AndrewThompson please have a look at the code . What mistake am I making?

Comment: The superScript part is not working

Comment: @AndrewThompson edited question description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure why your code doesn't work, as it does seem completely logical to do it this way. And I don't understand why some attributes work and some don't.

But according to [the Java 2D Tutorial: Using Text Attributes to Style Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/textattributes.html), the `SUPERSCRIPT` attribute should be set on the *font*, rather than on the text itself. Ie. using `Font.deriveFont(Map<Attribute, ?> attributes)`.

The following works for me (I modified your code slightly to not depend on your background file):

```
public class TextAttributesSuperscript  {

    static int curX = 10;
    static int curY = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AttributedString attributedString = new AttributedString("this is data. this data should be super script");

        attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLACK);

        Font superScript = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 18)
                .deriveFont(Collections.singletonMap(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER));
        attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, superScript, 30, 33);
        attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLUE, 30,33);

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(400, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_GASP);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        g.drawString(attributedString.getIterator(), curX, curY);
        g.dispose();

        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("output.png"));
    }
}
```